# Is this a good way to handle Web API UriTemplates?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net, wcf

I want to be able to do `/contacts/Matt%20Phillips` and `/contacts/1` and have both of them return a contact. The way I did that was to try and parse an `int` from the captured parameter and call the `Id` method instead of the `byName` method like so:

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="{param}"]
    public Contact SingleParam(string param)
    {
        int x;
        if (int.TryParse(param, out x))
        {
            return GetContactById(x);
        }
        else
        {
            return GetContactByName(param);
        }
    }

    private Contact GetContactByName(string param)
    {
        var contact = from c in contacts
                      where c.Name.Equals(param)
                      select c;
        if (!contact.Any())
        {
            return null;
        }
        return contact.Single();
    }

    public Contact GetContactById(int id)
    {
        var contact = from c in contacts
                      where c.ContactId == id
                      select c;
        if (!contact.Any())
        {
            return null;
        }
        return contact.Single();
    }
```

But it seems clunky to me. Anyone have suggestions for a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easier way. You can use uri templates to help you by making both handling methods operations.

```
[ServiceContract]
public class ContactsApi
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="{id}")]
    public string GetById(int id)
    {
        //return by id
    }

    [WebGet(UriTemplate="{first} {last}")]
    public string GetByName(string first, string last)
    {
        //return by name
    }
}
```

If you do a GET on /contacts/Matt%20Phillips the second method will get invoked.

Comment: Ah. I suppose the key is that I'm using the space between first and last name. If I was returning a list by first names for example then i wouldn't be able to do it

Answer (score 1):

Your question is already answered, but this is an addition to your LINQ statements.
By first using `Any()` and then `Single()`, you're executing two database queries.
You could save one, by using `SingleOrDefault()`, like this:

```
var contact = (from c in contacts
                where c.Name.Equals(param)
               select c).SingleOrDefault();
return contact;
```

Another addition, if you choose not to use `SingleOrDefault()`, first write the expected condition, then the exception:

```
if (contact.Any())
{
    return contact.Single();
}
return null;
```